# Group DriveItem not converting to PDF

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Microsoft Graph allows downloading documents and conversion to PDF. This functionality works well for me when downloading it from OneDrive for Business, but when used with Groups, the `format` parameter is ignored and I just get original content (no conversion).

A request with URL constructed as `/drive/root:/{path and filename}:/content?format=pdf` works and the doc is converted to PDF before downloading.

A request with a URL constructed  as `/groups/{group-id}/drive/root:/{path and filename}:/content?format=pdf`, however, ignores the conversion request.

I've tried with both `/v1.0` and `/beta` endpoints.

Relevant API doc is [Download the contents of a DriveItem](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_get_content) and next topic for content conversion.

Comment: I'm not sure why Groups would be failing here, I would expect it to work. Have you tested with multiple group drives? I'm curious if the type of Group or configuration might have something to do with this.

Comment: Marc, I did not try, because I have access to only one. Can it relate to some dogfooding? It's on microsoft.sharepoint.com.

Comment: I'm not aware of any issues but it's certainly possible. You may want to set up a [developer tenant](https://developer.microsoft.com/office/profile) for this, it will make debugging a lot easier (since you would have full control).